# How can I get DevExpress CollectionView's Selected Rows Properly in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, devexpress

I'm using devExpress CollectionView to show data :

```
<dxcv:DXCollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ReportsParameters}"
                       DisplayMember="VIEW_QUERY"
                       SelectionMode="Multiple"
                       SelectionChanged="DXCollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                       SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedReportsParameters}"
                       DisplayFormat="Query: {0}">
        </dxcv:DXCollectionView>
```

This "SelectionChanged" method doens't work as I expected. I wrote like this below but It doens't give me that "selectedItems" as a list, It gives always last item.
How can I get this "selectedItems" as a list ? Can you suggest me a wise way to accomplish this issue ?

```
private void DXCollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XamarinForms.CollectionView.CollectionViewSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (sender != null)

        {
            var dxColView = (DevExpress.XamarinForms.CollectionView.DXCollectionView)sender;
            if (dxColView != null)
                //Console.WriteLine(dxColView.SelectedItems.ToString());


                foreach (DynamicReportsParameters item in dxColView.SelectedItems)
                {
                    string query = Preferences.Get("query", "");
                    query += item.VIEW_QUERY + ';';
                    Preferences.Set("query", query);
                    Console.WriteLine(query);
                }
            var mList = dxColView.SelectedItems as List<DynamicReportsParameters>;

            foreach (var item in mList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.VIEW_QUERY);
            }




        }
}
```

Comment: So this only gives you a single item every time?

Comment: Yes. If it gives a list of selecteditems I couldn't find it. This is documentation : https://docs.devexpress.com/MobileControls/402266/xamarin-forms/collection-view/examples/selection I understand this like "pre select items".

Comment: Did you try to set the binding mode as two ways and then get the selecteditems from the viewmodel?

Comment: I didn't try it. I don't know how to do it, is there any tutorial to do that ? @Liyun

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I already added SelectedReportsParameters as a SelectedItems. Now I write a new command for collectionview tap command and I could check that SelectedReportsParameters count. Thank you for the idea, I could see what happens. :)

Comment: You can read the offiical document about [Binding mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode).